# Google Chrome: Scroll animation not working in Windows Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am using animate , scrolltop() to go to the form when clicking on btn. It works fine in my Ubuntu Chrome. But it does not work in Windows Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

```js
      
          $(function() {
                  $('a.scroll_page').bind('click', function(event) {
                      var $anchor = $(this);
                      $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        
                          scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                      }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
                      event.preventDefault();
                    
                  });
            
              });
```

```css
.content_div{
  height:400px;
}

.form_div{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  border:thin black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<a href="#download_ebook" class="btn scroll_page">Download</a>

<div class="content_div"></div>

<div class="form_div" id="download_ebook"></div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: works pretty well on my win chrome

Comment: strange. i have checked in 4-5 different devices. it doesn't work.

Comment: do you have console errors on thouse devices ?

Comment: It's working on my Windows Chrome browser. Try clearing caches.

Comment: yes. I have checked. there is no error. also I have cleared cache.

Comment: is there any other common way through which i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is working nicely in all if my windows browser. Please clear caches and then try again. Hope, it solves your problem.